# How to query in SQL that do not have matching row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

Hello the question is :

1. We want to find rows in the Salespeson table that do not have a matching row in Orders.

So far this is my code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Salesperson t1
INNER JOIN Orders t2 ON t1.ID  =  t2. salesperson_id
WHERE salesperson_id IS NULL
```

but it returns nothing. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `left outer` join, an `inner` join gives the opposite of what you want.

This is better expressed using `exists`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Salesperson sp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Orders o WHERE o.salesperson_id = sp.Id)
```

Comment: I ran this query and its giving me an error, HINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "o.salesperson_id".

Comment: Ah Yes I had the aliases the wrong way round - have corrected!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Salesperson s LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON s.ID = o.salesperson_id
WHERE o.salesperson_id IS NULL;
```

Note the changes to the query:

- The tables aliases are abbreviations for the table names, so the query is much, much easier to follow.
- All columns are qualified, to identify the table where they are coming from.
- The `SELECT` only selects from the first table.  Why bother with the second because all the values are `NULL`?